# How to add a button in a gmail add-on to trigger the function that I need?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I created this script:

```
function buildAddOn(e) 
{
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var threadID = message.getThread();
    var threadLabels = message.getThread().getLabels();

    for (var i = 0; i < threadLabels.length; i++) 
    {
        var labelN =  threadLabels[i].getName();
        var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelN);
        label.removeFromThread(threadID);
    }

    var newlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TEST");
    newlabel.addToThread(threadID);
}
```

It checks the labels of the thread I'm in at the moment and removing all and adding just one, the label: **TEST**

What I want is a button that when I press it, it triggers this script. 
I'm pretty new to code if there is a way to make it work would be very grateful for any help.

thank you

Comment: What is the `e` in your function parameter (_see:_ `function buildAddOn(e)`)? Is it the result of some loading? If yes, why not just run run the load process on button click? Button should be a visual with instance name and set to accept clicks via `xxx.buttonMode = true;` where `xxx` is your instace name...

Answer (score 1):

### You can use the [Card Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/) for creating buttons

- You can add your buttons to a [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button-set)
- Chose between different types of buttons, like e.g. the [textButton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button-set)
- Specify with [setOnClickAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setOnClickAction(Action)) which [action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action) you want to run (e.g. call your [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setFunctionName(String))).